# Iniciar com pastas iguais e arquivos diferentes

Tags: php, git, versionamento, bitbucket

Tenho um projeto que vinha mantenho somente copiando arquivos para o servidor via SSH. Alguns destes arquivos foram editados manualmente diretamente no servidor de produção. Agora estou iniciando o versionamento com Git no Bitbucket, e já realizei um *push* inicial dos arquivos que estão em minha máquina de desenvolvimento.

Como fazer agora para mesclar o que está no servidor de produção e o que já está no Git, sabendo que o servidor de produção tem alguns arquivos modificados diretamente lá, e que não contém estas modificações no repositório Git e nem na minha máquina de desenvolvimento?

Lembro que ainda não realizei nenhuma ação referente ao Git no servidor de produção. Estou em dúvida de como proceder a partir de agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o seguinte.

Suponha que seu projeto, no servidor, esteja na pasta `/var/www/projeto`. Clone o seu repositório em uma outra pasta, por exemplo, `/var/www/projeto_git`:

```
git clone <repositório> <pasta de destino>
```

O *branch* que será clonado será o padrão `master`. Crie um outro *branch* chamado, por exemplo, `servidor`:

```
git checkout -b servidor
```

Então, copie todos os arquivos da pasta do seu projeto para o seu repositório:

```
cp -R /var/www/projeto /var/www/projeto_git
```

Isso feito, comite os arquivos com uma mensagem bem clara (por exemplo, "arquivos do servidor") e envie-os para o servidor remoto:

```
git add --all
git commit -m <mensagem de commit>
git push -u origin servidor
```

Dessa forma você terá dois *branches* no seu repositório: o `master`, que contém o projeto original, e o `servidor`, que possui o seu projeto modificado com os arquivos do servidor em que está hospedado.

(Apenas um detalhe: já que você tem pouca experiência com Git, tome cuidado ao versionar arquivos com informações confidenciais em um repositório público; prefira repositórios privados.)

Por fim, caso você queira baixar o projeto modificado em seu ambiente de desenvolvimento, rode o seguinte comando:

```
git checkout -b servidor origin/servidor
```

Dessa forma, é possível comparar os dois *branches* (ou seja, quais arquivos existem em um *branch* e não no outro) e as diferenças entre arquivos com o comando:

```
git diff master..servidor
```

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado Rodrigo. Estou testando agora esta solução e é isso mesmo. Agradeço sua disposição em ajudar.